# Can't Reject a New Topic request for Docs

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-topics

I get an "An error occurred, Please try your action again" on trying to reject [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/89437).

I tried:

- "copied content"
- "other"

Both do the same... Also, attempted it from the queue (that's how I got there in the first place), and also directly through the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/react-native?tab=proposedchanges).

(At least commenting still works)

Comment: I had the same yesterday and so did at least one other user: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=32782378#32782378 I didn't find a pattern or root-cause. I assumed it was an local issue only affecting me.